# Did C. Ross have to manually re-tag all [dd] questions to [dnd]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Did C. Ross have to manually re-tag all [dd] questions to [dnd]?

If so, points to him, but it also means we need to hurry up and settle on tag syntax, sub-tagging, and removal of erroneous tag, else the next time that sort of an activity is undertaken it will be twice as ginormous/lame. (I'm not even linking to all those questions I'm referring to; they're all over the place!)

Comment: I retagged a *very* small number manually.

Comment: @C. Ross♦ - You're a good moderator, C. Ross. We don't deserve you :)

Comment: Just a note - you probably didn't have to retag at all, could have set up a synonym, right, and it would just drag them all over.

Comment: The problem with a synonym is that you don't get the highlighting in the question list.  I said that I like dd4.0.  Clicking that gets me all the right questions, but I don't get any highlighting in the question list for questions that are tagged with the dnd4.0 tag, even though they are synonyms.  Please excuse my ignorance.  Is it normal practice to remove the deprecated tags altogether at some point rather than have the synonyms hanging around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nah. We have awesome tools, yo.

Comment: Cool. I was feeling really sorry for him :'(